# Javascript new keyword difference in output

Tags: javascript

Why do I get 2 different output when I run in Chrome -> DevTools -> Sources and when I run in JSFiddle.

The code which I run is as follows

```js
function foo() {
    this.baz = "baz"
    console.log(this.bar + " " + baz);
}

var bar = "bar";
var baz = new foo();
console.log(baz.baz)
```

Output in chrome

```
undefined [object Object]
baz
```

Output in JSFiddle

```
"undefined undefined"
"baz"
```

Essentially chrome is telling me that `baz` is an object of type `{baz:"baz"}` but jsFiddle tells me it is undefined.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a standard page with that code on it is run the result is `undefined undefined` and then `baz`.

Inside the function, `baz` refers to the outer variable named `baz`, which is the instance that's being created (but hasn't been created yet - it'll be created after the `foo` function returns the instance). So, at that moment, it should be `undefined`.

But, the console is *not* like a standard webpage; it'll save previous values assigned to variables when you run it again. You must have run the code more than once - in which case, it's like doing

```js
function foo() {
    this.baz = "baz"
    console.log(this.bar + " " + baz);
}

var bar = "bar";
var baz = new foo();
console.log(baz.baz)

// you probably cleared the console manually at this point
// before running it again

function foo() {
    this.baz = "baz"
    console.log(this.bar + " " + baz);
}

var bar = "bar";
var baz = new foo();
console.log(baz.baz)
```

so the `[object Object]` you see is from a previous run's instance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you did not run the same code on chrome **twice**?

The first time `baz` is clearly undefined, but if you paste the same code again it has the value you already defined (`var baz = new foo();`).